# python script error

Tags: debian, kali-linux, python, error-handling

Recently, I redownloaded kali linux  version 2021.4. I did the normal set up command "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade". After I finished the update I proceeded to copy a github repo called Osintgram. I did all the configuration correct, but as soon as I executed the script I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/Osint/Osintgram/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from src.Osintgram import Osintgram
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/Osint/Osintgram/src/Osintgram.py", line 13, in <module>
    from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopy/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from geopy.geocoders import *  # noqa
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/__init__.py", line 223, in <module>
    from geopy.geocoders.algolia import AlgoliaPlaces
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/algolia.py", line 5, in <module>
    from geopy.geocoders.base import DEFAULT_SENTINEL, Geocoder
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/base.py", line 7, in <module>
    from geopy.adapters import (
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopy/adapters.py", line 55, in <module>
    import aiohttp
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .client import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 35, in <module>
    from . import hdrs, http, payload
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/http.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .http_parser import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/http_parser.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .helpers import NO_EXTENSIONS, BaseTimerContext
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py", line 667, in <module>
    class CeilTimeout(async_timeout.timeout):
TypeError: function() argument 'code' must be code, not str
```

I have searched the google for an answer but could not find one. Is there any suggestions on troubleshooting this issue and or possible solutions?

Comment: start by reading the error listing

Comment: https://issueexplorer.com/issue/custom-components/alexa_media_player/1446 Might be related.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/683250/100397 is related. Possibly a duplicate but difficult to tell without the context surrounding the included error traceback